# Best Solution for Tracing/Loging Web Service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, logging, asmx, trace

We have ASP.NET 4.5 web services (asmx) with a lot of projects and classes.
We need to recreate bugs in production enviroment so if a bug is reported we would like to view a log file so we can recreate the bug.

It will be a lot of work to write logger code lines in the solution projects.

Is there any logging add-in/extension that will do the work more rapidly?

Comment: _"It will be a lot of work to write logger code lines in the solution projects"_ - yeah you're kind of supposed to think of that before writing any line of code. Anyway what you're looking for is delivered by aspect-oriented programming, for example PostSharp, that can inject logging code into your classes. Try searching.

Answer (score 0):

We use WCF Message logging. It logs the entire xml that is sent into the web service.

If we have a problem in test or Production, we take the xml, put it into SOAP UI and run it against the web service. This Works well for stateless calculation services, for services that require state you could take a copy of Production to recreate the problem in test.

Here is how you can configure it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, but we use asmx. And logging the xml that is sent to the web service will not allow us to recreate threading issues that comes from multy-user simultaneous requests.